# How to fix this interaction bug between pgfplots and babel-french module?

Tags: pgfplots, luatex, babel, french

Here is an example of a minimum non-working case which is generating the bug:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \legend{a};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get this:

```
error: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/frenchb.lua:62: attempt to index a nil value
.
\endpgfpicture ...globally \endgroup \hss \egroup
                                                  \pgf@restore@layerlist@fro...
l.36 \end{tikzpicture}
```

If I remove the legend away, this is working well. But well, the legend is usually  kind of a required piece of information in a graph.

**EDIT:**

I just installed the latest TL version (net install): the bug is still there!

Comment: It compiles fine to me (I have an up to date version of MacTeX 2014).

Comment: Did you try the `babel` library of TikZ v3.00?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Are you sure: I've just run an update and do see this error.

Comment: TikZ v3.00 has a babel library for `babel` package clashes.

Comment: @JosephWright: I've updated a couple of hours ago, but a part from the warning messages on compatibility and empty axis, it compiles fine.

Comment: The error appears when `luatextra` is loaded. The error is in the Lua side and the error message doesn't appear in the `.log` file

Comment: @egreg: Oh, indeed I was checking the [log - my version](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3334279/new-tikztest.log)

Comment: TikZ chooses nullfont so it is not necessarily a font issue. Why do you use `luatextra` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*With recent version of frenchb (v3.1b), there is no bug.*

If you try the following code, there is no error:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \legend{a}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Advice:** If you compile a document via `lualatex` with `frenchb` (older than v3.1b) and `tikz` don't add superfluous *active* character in your TikZ code !  (In your example, the superfluous character is `;`)

Comment: The `;` here is not needed but is very common in TikZ syntax!

Comment: @Joseph: I second that. That part of my document already takes 2 minutes to compile (because I have a lot of graphs). I really don't want to spend my time adding or removing `;` while I could just put `;` everywhere and not bother about it. Don't get me wrong: from now on, I'll avoid putting `;` everywhere but as Joseph said, this is a very common syntax and this is working with (Xe)LaTeX and it was working with LuaLaTeX. I'll give you the best answer but will keep the bounty for someone finding a way to fix it (or will eventually give it to you if no one finds a fix).

Comment: @Manuel The `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` solves problems with usage of active characters in TikZ/pgf code. Not out of TikZ/pgf code...

Comment: Exactly, `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` is not working in this case.

Comment: @Gael True, you are right.

Comment: @Gael Superfluous ';' works with 'pdflatex', 'xelatex' and 'latex'... but it's not a feature of TikZ/pgf. It's just a fluke. Anyway, I reported this "bug" (?) to Daniel Flipo via the `fr.comp.text.tex` usenet group. I'm waiting its answer.